# sql - Possible to update two rows with different critera in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

This is for SqlCe,
I am trying to update a table and set won +=1 for a winner, and lost =1 for the loser.
I know I can do this with two different update statements but I was wondering if I could make update the winners "won" value at the same time that I update the losers "lost" value.

Basically just looking like this,

```
UPDATE player SET won = won +1 WHERE id = 0
UPDATE player SET won = lost +1 WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty but it works

```
UPDATE player SET won = won + CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END WHERE id in (0,1)
```

I'd personally stick with the two update statements

Comment: Yeah, I think it would be easier to do it with two, I will stick with that for now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: `SET won = CASE WHEN id=0 THEN won+1 ELSE lost+1 END`